# I want to create and populate list items in a JSP file using an Iterable from a Spring Controller

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I have the following controller and I want to get a variable length array of MediaFile objects to a JSP file so I can generate a list in html.

```
package project.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import project.MediaFileRepository;
import project.MediaFile;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;

@Controller
public class SearchController {

    @Autowired
    private MediaFileRepository repository;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/searchmedia", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String searchForm(Model model) {
        // This is what I want to get to the JSP file
        Iterable<MediaFile> mediaFiles = repository.findAll();

        // I could also generate the html here and put that into the file
        for (MediaFile mediaFile: repository.findAll()) {
            model.addAttribute("mediaFile", mediaFile);
        }

        return "search";
    }
}
```

I want to get something like this in the jsp file from an array of objects of length N:

```
<ul>
  <li>Info from Object 1 from array</li>
  <li>Info from Object 2 from array</li>
  .
  .
  .
  <li>Info from Object N from array</li>
</ul>
```

I've been trying to solve this for an hour. One thing about it is that this is for a group project and it's been decided not to use templating engines like thyme leaf (although, depending on the answers here, I might have to convince them to change that up).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put `Iterable` into the model:

```java
model.addAttribute("mediaFiles", repository.findAll());
```

Then loop in the JSP, using JSTL:

```jsp
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<html>
<body>
<ul>
  <c:forEach var="mediaFile" items="${mediaFiles}">
    <li><c:out value="${mediaFile.name}"/></li>
  </c:forEach>
</ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Spring has loosely coupled with UI components(JSP), So need to create any html from your Java code if the actual jsp is redirecting.

Change your code like this,

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/searchmedia", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String searchForm(HttpServletRequest request, Map<String, Object> map) {

    // This is what I want to get to the JSP file
    Iterable<MediaFile> mediaFiles = repository.findAll();

    map.put("mediaFiles", mediaFiles);

    return "search";
}
```

Now, in the Jsp get the map object

Use the standard function to check length provided by `JSTL` functions

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" prefix="fn" %>
```

Use the below code snippet

```
<c:choose>
<c:when test="${fn:length(mediaFiles) >= 1}">
<ul>
<c:forEach var="mediaFile" items="${mediaFiles}">
  <li>${mediaFile.file_name}</li>
</c:forEach>
</ul>
</c:when>
<c:otherwise>
   // Nothing to Display.
</center>
</c:otherwise>
</c:choose>
```